# Pharo Gofer, can it fallback to local package cache when offline?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Can I tell `Gofer` to fall back to the local package cache when no internet is available?

For example such that I can use

```
Gofer it
    squeaksource: 'CodePhoo';
    addPackage: 'CodePhoo';
    load
```

to setup an image when offline on the train? (In that case we can be sure that the packages are in fact available locally from a previous image setup.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Theoretically yes, the model of Gofer would support such things.

Practically no, because of missing support from the Monticello side.

Even though Monticello provides a MCRepositoryGroup, this code unfortunately throws all kinds of different errors when one of the repositories is not reachable. That probably makes sense in the context of the Monticello tools, but for Gofer that would need to be reimplemented.

Comment: I tried to add `MCCacheRepository default` as repository, but found that it fails cos `GoferReference >> #repositories` removes it again. Is there a particular reason for that?

Comment: No, in fact I fixed that in the latest version. I just cannot commit my fix because the server is down.